# Not able to create barcode image with french text

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I have tried to create the barcode image with french text, but it throws the below exception
barcode128 does not allow the invalid characters,

Note:
To create the barcode image i have used the itextsharp assembly.

Someone help me out to resolve this problem?

Code:

```
var content = "attribué"

var bc = new Barcode128
            {
                Code = content,
                StartStopText = false,
                CodeType = Barcode.CODE128,
                Extended = true,
                ChecksumText = false,
                GenerateChecksum = false,
            };

bc.CreateImageWithBarcode(cb, Color.BLACK, Color.BLACK);
```

Answer (score 2):

Code128 originally only support ASCII and to use ISO/IEC 8859-1 you have to add a FNC4 extension code:

```
FNC4 = '\u00c8'
```

#### Example:

```
    var content = "attribué"

    var encodedFNC = new StringBuilder(Barcode128.FNC4);
    encodedFNC.Append(encodedFNC4);
    ~~~
    var bc = new Barcode128
        {
            Code = encodedFNC.ToString(),
            ~~~
```

Note: I'm *assuming* iTextSharp supports it since FNC4 is defined, otherwise iText7 does...

Comment: Hi SushiHangover,

I hope here you have mentioned encodedFNC4 as my string content(content = "attribué").

But it won't work, correct me if am wrong

Comment: still i got exception after use this,
"System.ArgumentException: There are illegal characters for barcode 128 in 'attribué"